# SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE col1=$var1 and col2=$var2 and col3=$var3

Tags: php, mysql

**Music Database Site**:
I have a table named `ps_albums` with columns: `artist`, `album`, `genre_id`, and so on.
I also have a second table named `ps_users` with the following column: `user_id`, `date_joined`, `fave_genre_1`, `fave_genre_2`, `fav_genre_3` and other.

My overall goal is to display only the genres of music that a user selects for the top 3 favorite selections.

I am able to INSERT the `genre_id` of all 3 favorite genre selections into `ps_profiles` which hold this info. Now I need to be able to pull the 3 genres_id's and display only them instead off all genres by default.

So by default `SELECT * FROM ps_albums ORDER by DESC;`

Thus displaying ALL albums on the front page.

Now, when that user clicks 'My Favorite Genres' I do this...

```
$query= "SELECT * FROM  `ps_profiles` WHERE `user_id`= $user_id";
$row = @mysql_fetch_object(@mysql_query($query));

$genre1 = $row->fav_genre_1;
$genre2 = $row->fav_genre_2;
$genre3 = $row->fav_genre_3;
```

I want to be able to display all records from ps_albums according to the 3 favorite selections from `ps_profiles`.
How would I setup the select statement?

```
SELECT * FROM ps_albums WHERE genre=$genre1 AND genre=$genre2 AND genre=$genre3
```

How would I go about this? There are more then 10 genres but I only want to show the ones selected as favorites from the 3 columns.  Hopes this clarifys a bit more.

Comment: Can you please elaborate further? It's not really clear what you want to do.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM ps_albums WHERE genre in ($genre1,$genre2,$genre3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use either `OR`'s or `IN()` to match a column value with multiple possible value.

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE a=1 OR a=2 OR a=3;
SELECT * FROM t WHERE a IN(1,2,3);
```

So for your case, it could look something like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM ps_albums WHERE genre IN('$genre1', '$genre2', '$genre3')";
```

I added quotes in the query, I'm assuming genre's are strings?